# MySQL error "Column 'id' in from clause is ambiguous", but I have prefixed my "id" with a table

Tags: mysql

Given the query:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT score.*
FROM score
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON (tag.id_score = score.id)
INNER JOIN score AS score_1 USING (id)
WHERE
 (score.song_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
  OR score.artist_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
  OR score.creator_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
  OR tag.name LIKE '%[Upload]%')
 AND (score_1.song_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
  OR score_1.artist_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
  OR score_1.creator_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
  OR tag.name LIKE '%[Check OK]%')
```

I get `Column 'id' in from clause is ambiguous` in MySQL 5.1.37. Usually people fix this by adding an explicit table in front of their ambiguous columns, but here I've already did so: `(tag.id_score = score.id)`. Leaving the `LEFT OUTER JOIN tag` fixes the problem, but doesn't allow searching inside tags table.

Is this a bug in MySQL or I've missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will it not help if you change

```
INNER JOIN score AS score_1 USING (id)
```

to

```
INNER JOIN score AS score_1 (score_1.id_score = score.id)
```

Comment: yes, INNER JOIN score AS score_1 ON (score_1.id = score.id)
has removed the error message, but gave me no results. I think I need to use sub-queries/views and not join too many things together.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I've used subqueries sucessfully like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT
    DISTINCT score.*
FROM score
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON (tag.id_score = score.id)
WHERE
    (score.song_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
        OR score.artist_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
        OR score.creator_name LIKE '%[Upload]%' 
        OR tag.name LIKE '%[Upload]%')


) AS score_0 INNER JOIN ( SELECT
    DISTINCT score.*
FROM score
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON (tag.id_score = score.id)
WHERE
    (score.song_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
        OR score.artist_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
        OR score.creator_name LIKE '%[Check OK]%' 
        OR tag.name LIKE '%[Check OK]%')


) AS score_1 USING (id)
```